# Insert data into JSP Page and convert it into HTML and send it via Email

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I am new to Spring and Java. I want to send the data present in the model to jsp without controller and convert it into HTML to send it over email.

I tried

```
return new ModelAndView("ViewPage", "viewData", modelName);
```

Can someone help me on this?

Comment: Do you need dynamic email template or other ? Please, describe little more.

Comment: Yes, I need a dynamic template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best choice for dynamic email template is velocity template. 
In below example dynamic html code is generated using velocity template:
The source code is at [Velocity Template Source Code](https://github.com/devbhuwan/velocitytemplate)

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
    <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
    <version>1.7</version>
 </dependency>
```

**VelocityEmailGenerator.java**

```
package com.developerbhuwan.velocityemailtemplate;

import java.io.StringWriter;
import org.apache.velocity.VelocityContext;
import org.apache.velocity.app.VelocityEngine;
import org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeConstants;
import org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader;

/**
 *
 * @author developerbhuwan
 */
public class VelocityEmailGenerator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        VelocityContext velocityContext = new VelocityContext();
        velocityContext.put("user", "Ram");
        velocityContext.put("message", "You registration accepted");
        VelocityEngine velocityEngine = new VelocityEngine();
        velocityEngine.setProperty(RuntimeConstants.RESOURCE_LOADER, "classpath");
        velocityEngine.setProperty("classpath.resource.loader.class", ClasspathResourceLoader.class.getName());
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        velocityEngine.mergeTemplate("emailTemplate.vsl", "utf-8", velocityContext, writer);
        System.out.println("Email : " + writer.toString());

        /*
         String mailMessage = writer.toString();
         mailSender.sendMail(mailMessage, .........)
         */

    }
}
```

### emailTemplate.vsl

```
<html>
    <body>
        <h3>Hi ${user},</h3>
        <p>
            ${message}
        </p>
        <h3>
            Thank you
        </h3>
    </body>
</html>
```